# aot and RouterModule big size

Tags: angular

when I use aot with **angular 4**:

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

**my bundle size is : 82.00 kb**

when I added `RouterModule` to my app with no configs :

```
@NgModule({
  //..
  imports: [
    //..
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
  ],
  //..
})
```

**the bundle size becomes : 102 kb**.

as you see the bundle increases by 20kb this is too much.

is there a way to make the bundle size small even if I use the `RouterModule`?

thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you consider that as being too much ?

Comment: @YounesM I said that because it's a small app, and I want the bundle to be small